# ANT "copy" task does not perform. Files are not copied

Tags: ant

I am writing my first ANT script to build a WAR file for a web application that I created.  The web application works well on the Tomcat.

The file structure of my web application is:

- src
- build
- WebContent
- --- + META-INF
- --- + WEB-INF
- --- + --- + lib
- --- + --- + web.xml
- --- + JSP
- build.xml

My ANT script is able to create some directories.  And "javac" works.   I can see the compiled Java classes under the root/build/classes folder.

I tried to use the "copy" to do some packaging before building a WAR (I have read those previously posted relevant threads and tried to follow the examples). But, my "copy" tasks do not work. I do not see files are copied into the "build/war" directory; consequently, the "war" task is not doing anything.  Nevertheless, there is no error message on the console.  Here I post my ANT script and hoping to get some more help.  Thank you very much.

```
<echo>Define properties</echo> 
<property name="name" value="SchoolSchedule"/>
<property name="src" location="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="web" location="${basedir}/WebContent"/>
<property name="build" location="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="disDir" location="${build}/dis"/> 
<property name="warDir" location="${build}/war"/>

<property name="tomcat.webapps" value="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\webapps" />

<echo>time stamp</echo> 
<tstamp prefix="build-info">
    <format property="current-date" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy" locale="en" />
    <format property="current-time" pattern="hh:mm:ss a z" locale="en" />
    <format property="year-month-day" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" locale="en" />
</tstamp>

<echo>clean up previous build directories</echo>    
<target name="clean" description="Delete old build directories">
    <delete dir="${disDir}"/> 
    <delete dir="${warDir}"/>
</target>

<echo>create directories</echo>
<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${disDir}"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${warDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF"/>
    <mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</target>

<echo>start compiling</echo>        
<target name="compile" depends="clean, init" description="Compile main 
      source tree java files">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/classes" debug="on" />
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
              <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</target>

<echo>start building WAR file</echo>    
<target name="buildwar" depends="clean, init, compile">

    <!-- Packaging -->
    <copy todir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${build}/classes" />  
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${warDir}/WEB-INF">
        <fileset dir="${web}/WEB-INF" includes="web.xml" />      
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${warDir}">
        <fileset dir="${web}" includes="**/*.*" /> 
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="${disDir}/${name}.war" basedir="${warDir}" />                        

</target>
<echo>end building WAR file</echo>  

<target name="deploy" depends="init, compile, buildwar" description="Deploy application">
    <delete dir="${tomcat.webapps}/*.war" />  
    <echo>copy WAR file to Tomcat deploy directory</echo>
    <copy file="${disDir}/*.war" todir="${tomcat.webapps}" />
</target>
```

Comment: You can't use a wildcard in the file attribute. If you want more files at once, use a [ResourceCollection](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) or prior to ant v1.7 a [fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html). Or maybe in you case play around with the includes=... attribute of [copy](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)